# Having trouble importing data

Tags: sas

I have a dataset I'm trying to import. My code is:

```
DATA AlbumData;
    INFILE '/folders/myfolders/TopGrossingAlbumsR.txt' DLM=','  DSD MISSOVER FIRSTOBS=2;
    INPUT Album $ Artist $ ReleaseDate ANYDTDTE10. TotalCertifiedCopies 5.1 
ClaimedSales 3.0 Genre $;
RUN;
```

But the log of my output says there's many lines of invalid data. The first two columns have data that somewhat appears, but is cut off, so when I try to add an informat, such as

```
Album $30.
```

It then combines the data in this column with Artist. I have no clue how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example lines of data and the error messages from the log would help with the diagnosis.

If the file really is delimited then make sure you are using list mode input style and not formatted input style. The easiest way to insure this is to not include ANY informat specifications in the `INPUT` statement.

It is also good practice to define your variables explicitly using a `LENGTH` or `ATTRIB` statement instead of forcing SAS to guess at how you want them defined by how you first use the variable.

```
DATA AlbumData;
  INFILE '/folders/myfolders/TopGrossingAlbumsR.txt' DLM=','  DSD truncover FIRSTOBS=2;
  length Album $30 Artist $30 ReleaseDate 8 
         TotalCertifiedCopies 8 ClaimedSales 8 Genre $30 
  ;
  informat ReleaseDate ANYDTDTE.
  format ReleaseDate yymmdd10.;
  INPUT Album -- Genre ;
RUN;
```

If you do have to use an informat in the `INPUT` statement then be sure to use the `:` modifier before it.

Also do not include decimal place specification on an INFORMAT unless your intent is to divide any input strings that do not have a period in them by that power of 10.

> Nathan: ... these dice ain't got no spots on 'em. They're blank
>   Big Jule: I had the spots taken off for luck, but
>   I remember where the spots formerly were.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that decimal condition. Thanks for the clarification, I was trying to interpret little SAS book.

Comment: Why does the code need 

    INPUT Album - - Genre ;

That part I am confused about.

Comment: You need to tell what variables to input. `Album -- Genre` is a positional variable list.  You can type out all of the variable names again, but why bother?  Of course you need to make sure you have defined the variables in the same order as you need to read them from the text file.